# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when I am receiving a JSON response from an API

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have inserted user details in the user table using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. One address includes a special character which is `20, National Park's 1st floor`. Because of this special character, the JSON is unable to parse and throwing an error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

**PHP API**

```
$arr['permanent_address'] = $row_emp->permanent_address; // No forward shash
$arr['permanent_address'] = addslashes($row_emp->permanent_address); // add double slas
```

h

**JS code to parse the script**

```
employees = '<?php echo json_encode($employees); ?>';
employees = JSON.parse(employees);
```

**The employee variable looks like**

```
employees = '[{"user_id":"5b62f1568abb1","employee_type":"sub_admin","employment_type":"full_time","salutation":"mr","first_name":"Shan","last_name":"Biswas","email":"shanbiswas@rediffmail.com","country_code":"+91","phone_number":"8448412789","mailing_address":"20, National Park, 1st floor, Lajpat nagar 4","permanent_address":"20, National Park\\'s 1st floor, Lajpat nagar 4","permanent_state":"Delhi","permanent_city":"NEW DELHI","permanent_country":"India","permanent_zipcode":"110024","age":"","user_status":"active","date_of_birth":null,"created_at":"2018-08-02 05:56:06"}]';
```

I have added `addslashes()` function in the API to add slashes so that the error doesn't occur, but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $arr['permanent_address'] = addslashes($row_emp->permanent_address); // add double slash
> ```

You should almost never use `addslashes`. Use escape functions specific to your data format instead.

Remove the above line entirely. Your encoding comes next:

> ```
> employees = '<?php echo json_encode($employees); ?>';
> employees = JSON.parse(employees);
> ```

Don't do that.

JSON is a subset of JavaScript. Use it directly.

```
employees = <?php echo json_encode($employees); ?>;
```

Trying to wrap it in a string literal so you can pass it through a JSON parser is just asking for trouble.

If you **really** wanted to do that (and it is pointless!), then use a function that will take a PHP string and generate JavaScript source code from it. Don't try to encode it manually by adding quotes and escapes yourself.

```
employees = <?php echo json_encode(json_encode($employees)); ?>;
employees = JSON.parse(employees);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are double slashes("\\") to escape the special character. It should be just a single slash.

```js
var employees = '[{"user_id":"5b62f1568abb1","employee_type":"sub_admin","employment_type":"full_time","salutation":"mr","first_name":"Shan","last_name":"Biswas","email":"shanbiswas@rediffmail.com","country_code":"+91","phone_number":"8448412789","mailing_address":"20, National Park, 1st floor, Lajpat nagar 4","permanent_address":"20, National Park\'s 1st floor, Lajpat nagar 4","permanent_state":"Delhi","permanent_city":"NEW DELHI","permanent_country":"India","permanent_zipcode":"110024","age":"","user_status":"active","date_of_birth":null,"created_at":"2018-08-02 05:56:06"}]';

var object = JSON.parse(employees);
console.log(object);
```

Comment: I just enclosed the ADDRESS variable with addslashes(), if I remove it no forward slash is being added in it. I don't know how double slash comes

Comment: You've JSON encoded the data after encoding it to put in a string literal delimited with `'`. ```\``` is a special character in JSON and needs escaping.